# The onslide command in beamer with tikzcd

Tags: beamer, tikz-cd

Is it possible to use the `\onslide` command in beamer within the `tikzcd` environment? The following mwe gives an error.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Slide 1}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X
\arrow{r}{g}
\onslide<2->{\arrow[dashed,bend right]{rr}[swap]{\exists f\circ g}}
    \pgfmatrixnextcell 
Y\arrow{r}{f}
    \pgfmatrixnextcell 
Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @dcmst I read through that post and still am not sure how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: you are right, sorry, I retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `onslide*<2->` should solve your problem.  My trial also indicates that `only<2->` would work too. Since `onslide*` is equivalent to `only` from beamer view point.

[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Slide 1}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}%[row sep=3em,column sep=4.5em]
X
\arrow{r}{g}
\onslide*<2->{\arrow[dashed,bend right]{rr}[swap]{\exists f\circ g}}
        \pgfmatrixnextcell 
Y\arrow{r}{f}
        \pgfmatrixnextcell 
Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{frame}
```

Comment: This is useful. I wanted the content on slide 1 to be in the same place on slide 2 so I added \onslide*<1>{\arrow[white,dashed,bend right]{rr}[swap]{\phantom{\exists f\circ g}}} Thanks!

Comment: Good workaround, indeed.